# error " Unable to resolve "./component/Search" from "components\Description.js"

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm still new to expo
I try to resolve this problem but I found a dead road could someone help me? T.T
I try to connect search.js to description.js
So when someone press the button of the flatlist in search.js, it will go to description.js

I also get the  "Error while reading multipart response" in my phone.

```
\\app.js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

import Category from './components/Category';
import Search from './components/Search';
import Description from './components/Description';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <AppContainer />;
    }
}

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Category: {
        screen: Category,
    },
    Search: {
        screen: Search,
    },
    Description: {
        screen: Description,
    },
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

This is my Search.Js file

```
/*This is an Example of SearchBar in React Native*/
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList, ActivityIndicator, Platform, Button } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements';

export default class Search extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        //setting default state
        this.state = { isLoading: true, search: '' };
        this.arrayholder = [];
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                this.setState(
                    {
                        isLoading: false,
                        dataSource: responseJson,
                    },
                    function () {
                        this.arrayholder = responseJson;
                    }
                );
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }

    search = (text) => {
        console.log(text);
    };
    clear = () => {
        this.search.clear();
    };

    SearchFilterFunction(text) {
        //passing the inserted text in textinput
        const newData = this.arrayholder.filter(function (item) {
            //applying filter for the inserted text in search bar
            const itemData = item.title ? item.title.toUpperCase() : ''.toUpperCase();
            const textData = text.toUpperCase();
            return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
        });

        this.setState({
            //setting the filtered newData on datasource
            //After setting the data it will automatically re-render the view
            dataSource: newData,
            search: text,
        });
    }

    ListViewItemSeparator = () => {
        //Item sparator view
        return (
            <View
                style={{
                    height: 0.3,
                    width: '90%',
                    backgroundColor: '#ffc413',
                }}
            />
        );
    };

    render() {
        if (this.state.isLoading) {
            // Loading View while data is loading
            return (
                <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 20 }}>
                    <ActivityIndicator />
                </View>
            );
        }
        return (
            //ListView to show with textinput used as search bar
            <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
                <SearchBar
                    round
                    searchIcon={{ size: 30 }}
                    onChangeText={(text) => this.SearchFilterFunction(text)}
                    onClear={(text) => this.SearchFilterFunction('')}
                    placeholder="Type Here..."
                    value={this.state.search}
                />

                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.dataSource}
                    ItemSeparatorComponent={this.ListViewItemSeparator}
                    //Item Separator View
                    renderItem={({ item }) => 
                    <TouchableHighlight
                        onPress={() => Alert.alert('Touched')}
                        underlayColor='black'
                    >
                        <View>
                            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{item.title}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                        // Single Comes here which will be repeatative for the FlatListItems
                }
                    enableEmptySections={true}
                    style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    viewStyle: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        marginTop: Platform.OS == 'ios' ? 30 : 0,
    },
    textStyle: {
        padding: 10,
    },
});
```

This is my Description.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Button, View, SafeAreaView, Text, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import Search from './component/Search';

const Separator = () => <View style={styles.separator} />;

export default class Description extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                <View>
                    <Text style={styles.titless}>CATEGORIES</Text>
                </View>

                <View>
                    <Button
                        style={styles.box1}
                        title="FOOD"
                        color="#ffc413"
                        onPress={() => Alert.alert('Button with adjusted color pressed')}
                    />
                </View>
                <Separator />
                <View>
                    <Button
                        title="APPAREL"
                        color="#ffc413"
                        onPress={() => Alert.alert('Button with adjusted color pressed')}
                    />
                </View>
                <Separator />
                <View>
                    <Button
                        title="COMPUTER & ACCESORIES"
                        color="#ffc413"
                        onPress={() => Alert.alert('Button with adjusted color pressed')}
                    />
                </View>
                <Separator />
                <View>
                    <Button
                        title="SERVICES"
                        color="#ffc413"
                        onPress={() => Alert.alert('Button with adjusted color pressed')}
                    />
                </View>
                <Separator />
                <View>
                    <View style={styles.fixToText}>
                        <Button title="Search" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Search')} />
                    </View>
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }
}
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Search: {
        screen: Search,
    },
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        marginHorizontal: 16,
    },
    title: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        marginVertical: 8,
    },
    fixToText: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
    },
    separator: {
        marginVertical: 8,
        borderBottomColor: '#fff',
        borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    },
    titless: {
        marginTop: 1,
        paddingVertical: 8,
        borderRadius: 6,
        color: '#20232a',
        textAlign: 'left',
        fontSize: 25,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    box1: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 40,
        left: 40,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is in the same folder, so import it like this

```
import Search from './Search'
```

Comment: You probably have a problem in your folders hierarchy. Can you provide a screenshot ?

Comment: Ooooowhh I just got the answer! Thank yo much!